# export components from index file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have shared components folder when i created some components and i want to export all of them to index.js file and then export all of them from that file. thats how it looks from one of the components file:

```html
export default ToggleSwitch;
```

now in the index file i try to export them again, it looks like this:

```html
export { default as ToggleSwitch } from './ToggleSwitch';
export { default as Input } from './TextField';
export { default as Button } from './Button';
```

when i try to import one of the components if i import like this:

```html
import Button from '../../shared/components';
```

i get this error saying that '../../shared/components' does not contain a default export
and when i try to import it like this,

```html
import { Button } from '../../shared/components';
```

i get error saying Button is not exported from '../../shared/components'.

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please make producible example https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq

Comment: Share your button component.

Comment: The re-exporting module containing `export { default as Button } from './Button';`, exports it as `Button` not as `default`. Therefore, you cannot import it as if it were the `default` from that module. `import { Button } from '/re-exporting-module';` is correct

Comment: He still says named export not working... I think it's just typo somewhere... But we need a producible example

Comment: @DennisVash fair enough. I just wanted to clarify that point.

Comment: ye im dumb, i tried to export one file like this {Button} and like this Button. but i had another file i forgot about where it was like this Button. so i changed it also to {Button} and now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried importing as `import { Button } from 'shared/components';`?

For reference, the current codebase I work with has a similar structure for stores (flux stores) and this pattern works.

An example from the codebase: `import { ClickStore } from 'stores';`.

Comment: ye i tried that, i get this error: Attempted import error: 'Button' is not exported from '../../shared/components'.

Comment: nvm i had a file i forgot about where it was like this - import Button from 'shared/components'; and that what made the problem